# How to run multiple tests on different browser instances using cucumber at the same time

Tags: cucumber

I'm using Cucumber for my tests. Is there any way to run test scripts simultaneously on a browser(multiple instances), so that i can save time taken. I'm Using MAC OS X 10.7.4. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

See gradle

test {
      maxParallelForks = 500
      include 'Run*.class'
}